# Why does my GUI of smiley faces appear to be one color instead of all elements having their own separate, random colors?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, colors, java-2d

I'm attempting to draw these smiley faces out on a GUI and for their parts (eyes, smile, etc.) to be all random colors. However, when I use the `setColor` method for my variables, they all blend in with each other and I can't see the eyes, etc. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Smiley extends JPanel {
    //declare required variable
    //set the width of window
    public static final int w = 400;
    //set the height of window
    public static final int h = 400;
    //assign face diameter
    public static final int fd = 180;
    //initializes the face of x position
    public static final int xp = 10;
    //initializes the face of y position
    public static final int yp = 10;
    //initializes the width of eye
    public static final int we = 20;
    //initializes the height of eye
    public static final int he = 20;
    //set the Right eye's position on the x and y
    public static final int xre = xp + 40;
    public static final int yre = yp + 60;
    //set the left eye's position on the x and y
    public static final int xle = xp + 120;
    public static final int yle = yp + 60;
    //initialzes the width and height of the mouth
    public static final int mw = 80;
    public static final int mh = 50;
    //initializes the x and y position of mouth on the face
    public static final int xm = xp + 50;
    public static final int ym = yp + 90;
    //define the class variables of type Color
    public Color profile, nface, fsmile, eye;

    // Smiley constructor takes parameters for 4 colors that will be
    public Smiley(Color profile, Color nface, Color fsmile, Color eye) {
        //set the layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //initialize the parameters
        this.profile = profile;
        this.nface = nface;
        this.fsmile = fsmile;
        this.eye = eye;
        //call paint() method
        repaint();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Random random = new Random();
        Color color = new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
        gr.setColor(color);
        profile = color;
        nface = color;
        fsmile = color;
        eye = color;
        //set the color of profile of the face
        gr.setColor(profile);
        //draw the face
        gr.fillOval(xp, yp, fd + 7, fd + 7);
        //fill the color of face
        gr.setColor(nface);
        gr.fillOval(xp + 3, yp + 3, fd, fd);
        //fill the eye color
        gr.setColor(eye);
        //for draw right eye
        gr.fillOval(xre, yre, we, he);
        gr.setColor(eye);
        //for draw left eye
        gr.fillOval(xle, yle, we, he);
        //for smile color
        gr.setColor(fsmile);
        gr.drawArc(xm, ym, mw, mh, 180, 180);
    }
}
```

What I expect is something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DVFC.jpg

How would I go about achieving this?

And this is the code where I will implement the smileys:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; //determined to be useless and got rid of 
actionPerformed method
import javax.swing.*;
public class SmileyGrid extends JFrame {
    //object for SmileGrid class
    static SmileyGrid gs = new SmileyGrid();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gs.setSize(800, 800);
        gs.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        //call createFace function()
        gs.createGUI();
        gs.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SmileyGrid() {

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
            Smiley sp = new Smiley(Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.black);
            gs.add(sp);
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the code where you're creating/adding these `Smiley`s.

Comment: I edited my posting. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
profile = color;
nface = color;
fsmile = color;
```

These are supposed to be your 3 different colors. But you initialize all three to the **same** value! Instead, you would have to call the random function 3 times. Or to be precise: you should invoke that function repeatedly *until* your 3 colors are really different.

Alternatively: you could define 3 sets, each with 5, 10 different colors manually upfront. And then your code picks a random color from each set. Meaning: instead of using totally random colors, you could select sets of colors that always work together when mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You are assigning the same `Color` object to all your variables so naturally they have the same color. You'll need to generate new random colors for each of them rather than assigning `color` to all of them.

```
profile = new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
...
```